# Performance gains using straight ado.net vs an ORM?

Tags: performance, nhibernate, ado.net

would i get any performance gains if i replace my data access part of the application from nhiberate to straight ado.net ?

i know that NHibernate uses ado.net at its core !

Comment: I would say not much, when your code compiles most of the code gets optimized and converted from NHibernate to some other form which will obviously be more efficient than pure NHibernate and might be very close to the performance gain given by direct ado.net. Just a thought. Thanks!

Comment: This is almost impossible to answer because presumably you are doing some work above ADO.NET to translate the data readers into objects.  It's hard to know whether NHibernate will do that work more or less efficiently than your custom code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:**

It depends on what kind of operations you perform. You probably would get a performance improvement if you write good SQL, but in some cases you might get worse performance since you lose the NHibernate caching etc.

**Long answer:**

As you mention, NHibernate sits on top of ADO.NET and provides a layer of abstraction. This makes your life easier in many ways, but as all layers of abstraction it has a certain performance cost.

The main case where you probably would see a performance benefit is when you are operating on many objects at once, such as updating many entities or fetching a large amount of entities. This is because of the work that the NHibernate session does to keep track of which objects are modified etc. My experience is that the performance of NHibernate degrades significantly as the amount of entities in the session grows.

NHibernate has a lot of ways to improve performance and if you really know it well, you can get it to perform quite close to ADO.NET. However, if you are not that familiar with it, you can easilly shoot yourself in the foot, performance-wise. (Select N+1 problem, etc.)

There are some situations where you could actually get worse performance when switching form NHibernate to straight ADO.NET. This is because of the fact that the NHibernate abstraction layer introduces some features that can improve performance, such as caching. NHibernate also includes functionality for optimizing the generated SQL for the current database management system. For example, if you are using SQL Server it might generate slightly different SQL than if you are using Oracle.

It is worth mentioning that it does not have to be an all or nothing kind of situation. You could use NHibernate for the 90% of your database access for which it works great, and then use straight SQL for the 10% where you do complex queries, batch inserts/updates etc.